# Runtime Error on Compilation when using Latexmk

Tags: miktex, windows, latexmk, compilation-error

This morning I was editing a LaTex document when all of a sudden the continuous compilation stopped working. I tried recompiling the file and received this error:

```
2021/08/07 20:36:53 Rollbar error: empty token
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x121917c]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/ActiveState/cli/internal/locale.T(0x1ec6d62, 0x15, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x206a220, 0x8)
    D:/a/cli/cli/internal/locale/locale.go:119 +0x5c
github.com/ActiveState/cli/internal/language.init()
    D:/a/cli/cli/internal/language/language.go:69 +0x4e
2021/08/07 21:19:04 Rollbar error: empty token
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x121917c]
```

I tried restarting my computer and recompiling yet it didn't seem to work. I'm not sure what the error message means or how to fix it, but I've tried compiling another minimal tex file and that also didn't work.

Currently I'm using MikTex on Windows and VimTex to run the LatexMk package.
I could compile the same file with the xelatex command, but the same error appears when I try to compile using latexmk from the command line.

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: This is entirely unlike any error I've seen.  (My immediate reaction on seeing "ActiveState" in the diagnostics is that there is a serious bug in your installation of ActiveState perl.)  Could you add to the screen output, everything from the command line you entered to the error message you showed.  This will show what latexmk did, if it did anything at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I searched for "rollbar error" under ActiveState perl and found [others who've had the same problem.](https://community.activestate.com/t/activepython2-7-windows10-64bits-suddenly-c-python-rollbar-error-empty-token-message/6998) I followed their suggestion, deleting the config.yaml file and reinstalling ActiveState Perl and it started working again.